# Meaning of “at least initially”

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does "at least initially" mean? I've heard this but don't understand this phrase.

Answer (score 1):

"At least initially" expresses the idea that your statement about something is, or was, only true in the beginning. It is similar to the phrase, "At first".

"Most diets work, at least initially." This means that when you start a diet, you will probably lose some weight. However, over time, you may be less successful.

"At least initially, he was nice to me." This suggests that the person was nice at the beginning of your relationship, but eventually turned into a jerk.